# nested rollmean - how to avoid NA's from each DF edge

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, zoo

I'm using `rollmean()` for 4 and 5-year averages of time-series data. The averages cannot be counted across groups ("Grade" in df), so I'm using `purrr::nest()`.

I understand I can replace the value with 0, say, but am wondering what other approaches exist without 0-fill?

The end result I'm looking for would be a rolled mean by grouped variable, with as few NA's as possible - I feel my approach fails this last point.

**Data:**

```
csr_ <- tribble(~Year_, ~Grade, ~AttndRise,
    2016,"K5", 1.0000000,
    2017,"K5", 1.0000000,
    2018,"K5", 0.7562500,
    2016, "Gr. 1", 0.9448276,
    2017, "Gr. 1", 1.0000000,
   2018, "Gr. 1", 0.7625000,
    2016, "Gr. 2", 1.0000000,
     2017, "Gr. 2", 1.0000000,
   2018, "Gr. 2", 0.8709677,
 2016, "Gr. 3", 1.1240876,
  2017, "Gr. 3", 1.0000000,
  2018, "Gr. 3", 0.8467153,
 2016, "Gr. 4", 0.7857143,
  2017, "Gr. 4", 1.0000000,
  2018, "Gr. 4", 0.9635036,
  2016, "Gr. 5", 0.7685950,
  2017, "Gr. 5", 1.0000000,
 2018, "Gr. 5", 0.9480519,
 2016, "Gr. 6", 0.9462366,
 2017, "Gr. 6", 1.0000000,
 2018, "Gr. 6", 1.0247934)
```

**Process**

```
csr_ %>% 
  group_by(Grade) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                      mutate(four_year = rollmean(x= AttndRise, k = 3, align = "center", fill = NA )))) %>%
  unnest()

##result

# A tibble: 21 x 4
   Grade Year_ AttndRise four_year
   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
  K5     2016     1        NA    
  K5     2017     1         0.919
  K5     2018     0.756    NA    
  Gr. 1  2016     0.945    NA    
  Gr. 1  2017     1         0.902
  Gr. 1  2018     0.762    NA    
  Gr. 2  2016     1        NA    
  Gr. 2  2017     1         0.957
  Gr. 2  2018     0.871    NA    
 Gr. 3  2016     1.12     NA    
# … with 11 more rows


#note that this smaller data set I have reduced k to 3 instead of 4 & 5.
```

The result is more exaggerated with the smaller dataset, with the larger, we can see how each "edge" of a nested DF (first and last year of each grade) is given an `NA` value:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what output is wanted but key possibilities are to use (1) fill= to fill in the NA values, (2) rollapply(..., partial=TRUE) to compute partial means or (3) use na.omit(X) where X is the result with NAs to simply remove those rows..

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks for checking the post, apologies for lack of clarity. I've posted an answer below which somewhat solves my issue of wanting to fill the NA values with other mean values, however I can't replicate the same on my larger dataset.

Comment: Suggest you just use (2).

Comment: Ah yes, I tried it when I saw your post and had a similar result, but tried again and it worked. no need for that ifelse nonsense...thanks @G.Grothendieck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
csr %>% 
  group_by(Grade) %>% 
  arrange(Grade, desc(Year)) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                      mutate(four_year = rollapply(AttndRise, 4, mean, partial = TRUE),
                             five_year = rollapply(AttndRise, 5, mean, partial = TRUE))
                    )
         ) %>%
  unnest()
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 378 x 9
   Grade FakeCrudeBirthRate FakeFertilityRate Year    AttndRise Year_ Cohort     four_year five_year
   <fct>              <dbl>             <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 K5                  11.9              2.28 2018-19     0.756  2018 Elementary     0.919     0.919
 2 K5                  11.9              2.28 2017-18     1      2017 Elementary     0.939     0.939
 3 K5                  11.9              2.28 2016-17     1      2016 Elementary     1         0.951
 4 K5                  11.9              2.28 2015-16     1      2015 Elementary     1         1    
 5 K5                  11.9              2.28 2014-15     1      2014 Elementary     1         1    
 6 K5                  11.9              2.28 2013-14     1      2013 Elementary     1         1    
 7 K5                  11.9              2.28 2012-13     1      2012 Elementary     0.992     0.994
 8 K5                  11.9              2.28 2011-12     1      2011 Elementary     1.01      1.01 
 9 K5                  11.9              2.28 2010-11     0.969  2010 Elementary     1.05      1.04 
10 K5                  11.9              2.28 2009-10     1.07   2009 Elementary     1.05      1.04
```